# How to create tabular format in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

Hello i am trying to make form using tabular format like
[image]

Because my form contain is more than 50 textbox so form height is larger so i think in tabular format.

Please help me or suggest best way how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is the IconTabBar that provides a container with multiple tabs.
Have a look at the [Explored app](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.IconTabBar/samples).